# Trouble with for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

We just learned for loops in class for about five minutes and we were already given a lab. I am trying but still not getting what I need to get. What I am trying to do is take a list of integers, and then only take the odd integers and add them up and then return them so if the list of integers was [3,2,4,7,2,4,1,3,2] the returned value would be 14

```
def f(ls):
    ct=0
    for x in (f(ls)):
        if x%2==1:
            ct+=x
    return(ct)


print(f[2,5,4,6,7,8,2])
```

the error code reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ian/Documents/Python/Labs/lab8.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(f[2,5,4,6,7,8,2])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Iterate over `ls`, not `f(ls)`.

Comment: Missing parens...: `print(f([2,5,4,6,7,8,2]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a couple of minor mistakes:

```
def f(ls):
    ct = 0
    for x in ls:
    #       ^     Do not call the method, but just parse through the list  
        if x % 2 == 1:
            ct += x
    return(ct)
    #     ^  ^ parenthesis are not necessary 

print(f([2,5,4,6,7,8,2]))
#      ^               ^    Missing paranthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parenthesis in the function call

```
print(f([2,5,4,6,7,8,2]))
```

rather than

```
print(f[2,5,4,6,7,8,2])
```